# How To Update JQuery Progress Bar Value from a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Problem Regarding the JQuery Progress Bar.

I Need to set the Value of the Progress bar with the Value stored in a Javascript Variable.

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
{
    var text = $('.Gadget').find('input[name="Percentage"]').val();


 $(function() 
{
    $( ".ProgressBar" ).progressbar({
    value: 59
});

});
```

});

The Above code works fine, but as there is Value 59 the value is always Constant.

What I Really need is that instead of the 59, there will be the value of the text Variable.

Note: if I Put Value:text, the Progress bar disappears

Thank You,
Andrew Borg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it in the single document.ready handler. Use `parseInt()` to make it numeric:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var text = $('.Gadget').find('input[name="Percentage"]').val();

    $( ".ProgressBar" ).progressbar({
       value: parseInt(text)
    });

});
```

Comment: Hah A Simple parseInt XD I spend 4 hours Plus on this ='[

Comment: Just a warning since this is a user input, you should probably use `parseInt(text, 10)`. Otherwise, if a user put a lead 0 on the percent, it would parse in base 8.